# clustering a set of coordinates based on their distance with each other

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, or-tools

I am trying to make a cluster of sites which are closer to each other. I have coordinates of the sites and have generated their distance matrix also. I earlier used google or tools to generate optimized routes but I rather need to cluster the sites in groups.
Find below the sample distance matrix.

```
data['distance_matrix'] = [
    [
        0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354,
        468, 776, 662
    ],
    [
        548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674,
        1016, 868, 1210
    ],
    [
        776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164,
        1130, 788, 1552, 754
    ],
    [
        696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822,
        1164, 560, 1358
    ],
    [
        582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708,
        1050, 674, 1244
    ],
    [
        274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628,
        514, 1050, 708
    ],
    [
        502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856,
        514, 1278, 480
    ],
    [
        194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320,
        662, 742, 856
    ],
    [
        308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662,
        320, 1084, 514
    ],
    [
        194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388,
        274, 810, 468
    ],
    [
        536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764,
        730, 388, 1152, 354
    ],
    [
        502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114,
        308, 650, 274, 844
    ],
    [
        388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194,
        536, 388, 730
    ],
    [
        354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0,
        342, 422, 536
    ],
    [
        468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536,
        342, 0, 764, 194
    ],
    [
        776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274,
        388, 422, 764, 0, 798
    ],
    [
        662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730,
        536, 194, 798, 0
    ],
]
```

Need some suggestions to solve this problem. I am using python 3 and used or tools earlier to generate routes.

Comment: Take a look at the [clustering section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) of scikit-learn lbrary. You can start with something easy like Kmeans

Comment: Note that [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) will require the coordinates of the sites, not the matrix of pairwise distances. If you absolutely want to use this matrix, one possibility is [KMedoids](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids.html) - but I wouldn't recommend it if you do have the coordinates.